or tools flexible job shop intervals with multiple machines and per machine availability per job
I have been looking at OR-tools flexible job shop examples, specifically around machine jobs with per job durations. I see examples for this base problem problems but not for a way to specify specific times of day that particular jobs can be done on a machine.
How would I approach implementing an additional constraint where the machine can do specific jobs during specific time frames? Each job would have a different per machine list of time restrictions, I'm just trying to get this baseline figured out before approaching a similar multi machine situation.

Can you precompute the possible start dates, and restrict the domain of the start variables?

I can precompute the machine start/stop dates for when it is available to task
